# login url session rewrite

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cookies

I have an issue with login session. Basically the flow is like this:

- user creates account and defines a username;
- user logins using url 'http://[username].website.com'
- (coded in php & mysql, using session cookie)

My problem is: when trying to directly login from the index page 'www.website.com' I don't manage to get my user logged to his URL http://username.website.com

/// EDIT ///

Let say i have opened url "www.example.com" and created a session variable in this url. Now i want to access that session variable in url "test.example.com". How to do that? any solution welcomed

/// EDIT2 ///

In the top of every php file i have used the below code but my session variable was destroyed and i can't access the session variable in another page. I have also set session.cookie_domain = ".website.com" on "php.ini" file.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.website.com');
```

session_name("sessionid");
session_start();

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to redirect the user or something to their own subdomain site?  If so can you show some code for us to help with.

Comment: Make sure that your cookie is set to be accessible across all subdomains. ie '.mydomain.com'

Comment: Please show some login code and the session setup code.

Comment: Let say i have opened url "www.example.com" and created a session variable in this url. Now i want to access that session variable in url "test.example.com". How to do that? any solution welcomed

Comment: php.ini should be: session.cookie_domain = ".example.com" and then also start your session as: ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );

Comment: In the top of every php file i have used the below code but my session variable was destroyed and i can't access the session variable in another page. I have also set session.cookie_domain = ".website.com" on "php.ini" file.

ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.website.com');
session_name("sessionid");
session_start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As minaz mentioned in the comments, make sure that the cookie you're setting on www.website.com is valid for domain-matching on ".website.com".

If you're still not sure whats happening, try playing around with wget (http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) using --save-cookies, --load-cookies and --debug.